# I got Target group not attached to the Auto Scaling group error while doing blue green deployment through code deploy

Tags: aws-code-deploy

I have been trying blue green deployment with code deploy, but it throws an error: **The following validation error occurred: Target group not attached to the Auto Scaling group (Service: AmazonAutoScaling; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: cd58091b-fe83-4dcf-b090-18c3b3d2dbbc; Proxy: null)**

Though the policy has been applied to create target groups:

codedeploy:GetDeployment

elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups

autoscaling:AttachLoadBalancers

autoscaling:AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups

Does anyone could help me to sort out the issue & what am i missing?

The following is the error i encounter.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GZa8.png)

Answer (score 2):

In our case, we managed to fix it the hard way by contacting AWS support team. Briefly about our app, we run Magento application behind an application load balancer with autoscaling, and the deployment is managed using AWS CodeDeploy on blue/green deployment.

We spent several days figuring out what's going on. Others suggested that there might be issue with IAM permissions, but we didn't touch that for months and deployment has never had any issues.

AWS' rep replied to us and said that in our case, there is a known issue / limitation on AWS Codedeploy that it **currently don't support Blue/Green deployments based on ASGs that use Target Tracking scaling policies, because currently they don't attach the Green ASG to the original target group, and this is a requirement when Target Tracking scaling policies is enabled on the autoscaling group**.

We then realized that we did some minor changes on our autoscaling groups' dynamic scaling policies that we switched from "CPU utilization"-based metrics to "Request count". **Reverting it back to CPU utilization-based metrics** solved the issue and we can run the deployment successfully.

Hope it helps as this error seems not to be documented in AWS doc.